# Connection between ratio of magnitude of eigenvalues and ratio for singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

Let $A$, $B$ be a square, complex $4 \times 4$ matrices such that $Tr(A) = Tr(B) = 0$  Let $s_i(X)$ be i-th biggest singular value of matrix X. Let $\lambda_i(X)$ be i-th biggest eigenvalue (by magnitude).

From the fact that $A$ is traceless we have $\sum_{i=1}^4\lambda_i(A) = 0$, we have $\lvert \lambda_1(A) \rvert \leq \sum_{i=2}^4 \lvert \lambda_i(A) \rvert$. With that

$$
\frac{\lvert\lambda_1(A)\rvert}{\lvert\lambda_1(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_2(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_3(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_4(A)\rvert} \leq \frac{\lvert\lambda_2(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_3(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_4(A)\rvert}{\lvert\lambda_2(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_3(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_4(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_2(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_3(A)\rvert + \lvert\lambda_4(A)\rvert} =\frac{1}{2}
$$

I wonder if we from that we can deduce something about analogous ratio for singular values $\frac{s_1(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i(A)}$ or squares of singular values $\frac{s_1^2(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i^2(A)}$ (eigeinvalues of $A^HA$).
With $\lvert\lvert A\rvert\rvert^2_F + \lvert\lvert B\rvert\rvert^2_F = \frac{1}{4}$, where $\lvert\lvert X\rvert\rvert_F$ is a Frobenius norm of $X$, I saw that ratio $\frac{s_1^2(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i^2(A)}$
$$
\frac{s_1^2(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i^2(A)} \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: No, your desired inequality is false.  For a non-normal matrix the modulus of eigenvalues tells you almost nothing about the singular values (except the latter log-majorizes the former for invertible matrices).  E.g. $A=B:=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 100\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{matrix}\right]$.  You should be able to eyeball the fact that $\sigma_1 \geq 100$ but $ \sum_{k=1}^4 \sigma_k^2 = \big \Vert A\big \Vert_F^2 = 100^2 +4$ so all the other singular values are very small.

Comment: @user8675309: I did not mention the limit on Frobenius norm. Edited the post.

Comment: Again considering the special case of $A=B$ your desired inequality is $s_1(A)^2  \leq \sum_{i=2}^4 s_i^2(A)$  which is which holds for $A$ *iff* iit holds for $\lambda \cdot A$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R-\big\{0\big\}$.  I.e. your new Frobenius norm constraint changes nothing.

Comment: @user8675309, you are correct. That inequality will not be satisfied. But still the ratio remains of interest to me. In simulations I can see that square of operator norm to square of frobenius norm is always smaller than 1/2. Will update the post. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've already addressed this.  Do you really not understand that $\frac{s_1^2(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i^2(A)} \leq \frac{1}{2} \iff s_1(A)^2  \leq \sum_{i=2}^4 s_i^2(A)$?  You are demonstrating why people should study actual mathematics instead of naively following numerical calculations which are prone to estimation errors, roundoff, etc.  Note: if one replaces that $100$ in the top right corner of $A$ with $\delta \in \mathbb R$ then it implies the only possible upper bound is the trivial one, i.e. $\frac{s_1^2(A)}{\sum_{i=1}^4s_i^2(A)} \leq 1$.